# Queryable custom orderby

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this code:

```
les = query.OrderBy(le => le.Lemma, StringComparer.Create(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar"), true))
   .Skip((page - 1) * searchNumber)
   .Take(searchNumber)
   .ToList();
```

It produces an error that the order by query cannot be translated into a database query. I could have used `ToList()` to query the whole thing and then order it at will, but that I suppose would be bad to do for the performance.

How can I work around this issue.

Comment: use system.linq.dynamic. It allows you to enter a string in orderby clause https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

Answer (score 0):

Using a stored procedure seems to the trick.